# Convert multiple video Blobs into one and save it

Tags: javascript, electron, blob, mp4, webm

I record the screen and push a blob into an array, when it´s avaible. In the end I want to save it to a webm or a mp4 file. I tried converting it to a new blob and then save it as an arraybuffer, but that didn´t worked out.

```
function recordScreen() {
        blobs = [];
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(localstream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
            blobs.push(event.data);
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            stopRecording();
        }, 7000);
}

    function stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        console.log(blobs);
        //But how to save it to a mp4 or a webm?
    }
```

//UPDATE
Ok now its written to the file but it is not playable.

```
function recordScreen() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(localstream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        chunks.push(event.data);
    }
    recorder.start();
    setTimeout(() => {
        stopRecording();
    }, 7000);
}

function stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    setTimeout(() => {
        toArrayBuffer(new Blob(chunks, {type: 'video/webm'}), function(ab) {
            var buffer = toBuffer(ab);
            var file = `example.webm`;
            fs.writeFile(file, buffer, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Failed to save video ' + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Saved video: ' + file);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
}

function toArrayBuffer(blob, cb) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        let arrayBuffer = this.result;
        cb(arrayBuffer);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}

function toBuffer(ab) {
    return Buffer.from(ab);
}
```

Comment: `blobs = event.data` doesn't add `event.data` to the array. It **replaces** the array (the first time) with the blob, then replaces that blob with the next one, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yeah added that for testing prupose and tried saving one blob as an arraybuffer but didn´t went as plannend and video is not playable

Comment: What is `localstream`?

Comment: @RockySims it´s a MediaStream

Comment: Also what do you mean by save? Are you trying to post it to a server and save it? Or do you just mean play the video in the browser? Or allow user to download it as a file?

Comment: @RockySims It´s an Electron app and I just want to save it to a mp4 or a webm file locally.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first answer ever...It's old but maybe I can save some time to someone. Rigth now I'm working in something like that, and I resolve this situation like that:
1-In the ondataavailable event push the data in the result array.
2-In the onstop event create a new blob with the array.
Example code:

```
    videoRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    event.data.size > 0 && videoChunksArray.push(event.data);
};

videoRecorder.onstop = () => {
    let blob = new Blob( videoChunksArray, {
        type: "video/webm",//your own type here
    });
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "PRUEBA.webm";//your own name here
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```